# ImageSearch - tollerance, what are the units?

Tags: autohotkey

The AHK ImageSearch function accepts a tollerance like:

```
ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, *50 image.png
```

but what the `*50` number mean and what is the range? Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `50` in `*50` is the allowed variation of the RGB value of each pixel during `ImageSearch`. It ranges from 0-255. The default is 0 and `ImageSearch` will only match exact colours, and setting it all the way to 255 will match all colors.

The [AHK doc](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm#Parameters) states that:

> ***n** (variation): Specify for n a number between 0 and 255 (inclusive) to indicate the allowed number of shades of variation in either
>   direction for the intensity of the red, green, and blue components of
>   each pixel's color. For example, `*2` would allow two shades of
>   variation. This parameter is helpful if the coloring of the image
>   varies slightly or if *ImageFile* uses a format such as GIF or JPG that
>   does not accurately represent an image on the screen. If you specify
>   255 shades of variation, all colors will match. The default is 0
>   shades.

For ImageSearch, I generally use uncompressed BMP files cropped from screenshots and use the default tolerance for exact color matching.

Comment: Thank you. I am understanding it correctly, so if one pixel will differ completely (black and white), so even if one pixel, there will be no match? Is there any option how to match even if there are small different values (like match 95% surface/pixels)?

Comment: Yes, if one pixel is outside of the tolerance you specified, there will be no match. To answer your second question, I am not aware of such libraries, built-in or external, that enables "fuzzy" image search. Do you have an area of the screen that is 100% repeatable, regardless of how small it is? If so, you can shrink the area for which you're performing `ImageSearch`, and make sure the selected area is somewhat unique.